Angle difference between two points on an ellipse
I am trying to code something with images and I can not seem to find the answer online.
If you can see the attached picture, how do I find angle A? Note the Cx, and Cy are > 0 and that the y axis is reversed so that the y axis starts at the top left and down is positive whilst x axis is standard.
Thanks


Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Do you know about the dot product?

No not really, looking at it would I change my x,y coordinates to polar coordinates?

You can use the cosine rule: $$\cos A={CP_1^2+CP_2^2-P_1P_2^2\over 2P_1P_2}$$

There are many ways to do this. If you know something about how the points were found on the ellipse in the first place, it might make even more methods possible.

You can just consider this a problem of the direction of vectors in the plane, and look up how to use the atan2 function.

Find their slopes,
$$m_1=\frac{Y_1-C_y}{X_1-C_x}\\
m_2=\frac{Y_2-C_y}{X_2-C_x}$$
And then we can use the following identity,
$$\tan\theta=\bigg|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\bigg|$$
To get angle $\theta$ between them.
If I find any cool relations due to their elliptical presence, I'll edit it to this answer
Edit
This can be done if you know the equation of the ellipse.
$$\frac{(x-C_x)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-C_z)^2}{b^2}=1$$
If you know $a$ or $b$, then we'll using parametric form of ellipse formula, where
$$x-C_x=a\cos t, y-C_y=b\sin t$$
Then in this case we are just doing $$|t_1-t_2|\\=\bigg|\arccos\bigg(\frac{X_1-C_x}{a}\bigg)-\arccos\bigg(\frac{X_2-C_x}{a}\bigg)\bigg|$$
For $b$ it will be a similar formula with $\arcsin$ instead

Some care is required with the $\tan \theta$ formula. Usually there is an acute solution and an obtuse solution, and the formula doesn’t tell you which one is correct.

@DavidK We can remove the mod in that case. Will that be helpful?

The problem is that there are always two points on the ellipse that lie on the same line through the center, and you get the same slope from either one. So any formula that depends only on slopes cannot distinguish those points. Hence two possible angles that have to be distinguished by other clues.

@DavidK does the answer involving the ellipse equation work? Or is it faulty as well? I've put it to test with quite a few examples :") any exceptions are welcome

That has two issues: arccos cannot distinguish the top half of the ellipse from the bottom, and when that doesn’t mess up the result, you get the difference between the parametric angles, not the actual angle.

@DavidK wouldn't that be the same?

No. Consider $C_x=C_y=0$, $a=\sqrt3$, $b=1$, $t=\pi/4$. You get $x=\sqrt6$, $y=\sqrt2$, and the vector $(\sqrt6,\sqrt2)$ makes an angle $\pi/6$ with the $x$ axis, but arccos says $\pi/4$.

@DavidK ohh. Alright I'll edit my answer accordingly
